# Applications centre doesn't open

Tags: applications, appcenter

I've just installed the last stable version but the applications centre doesn't work, clicking on the icon nothing happens, any solution?

Comment: thanks gireesh for commands.I faced same problem after installation but i solved it.

Comment: Open AppCenter and wait for some time ( based on your Internet connection ). Because, for the first time it load the data for AppCenter. So, for that reason it will take little or more time!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue after installation.

Run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then open software-center.
Its worked for me.